# Converting ASCII to an image

Tags: ruby, image, fractals

So after I finished [my fractal generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/99192/fractal-generator), I decided that text is ugly, at least compared to pictures, so I made a text-to-picture converter:

```
require 'chunky_png'
require 'etc'
require 'pathname'

class Array
  def chunk(chunk_size)
    self.each_with_index.with_object(Array.new(size / chunk_size) { [] }) do |(elt, ind), result|
      result[ind / chunk_size] << elt
    end
  end
end

raise ArgumentError, 'Wrong argument number. Run with -h to see usage.' unless ARGV.length % 2 == 1

filename = ARGV.pop

colors = Hash[
    ARGV.chunk(2).map do |(char, color)|
      color = ChunkyPNG::Color.from_hex(color)
      [char, color]
    end
]

text = []
text << $_.chomp.chars until $stdin.gets.nil?
row_length = text[0].length
raise ArgumentError, 'Input cannot be jagged' unless text.all? { |row| row.length == row_length }

image = ChunkyPNG::Image.new(row_length, text.length, ChunkyPNG::Color::WHITE)
text.each.with_index do |row, y|
  row.each_with_index do |char, x|
    raise ArgumentError, "No valid color provided for `#{char}`" if colors[char].nil?
    image[x, y] = colors[char]
  end
end

image.save(filename)

puts "Image saved to #{File.join(Dir.getwd, filename)}"
```

Note that it uses the [ChunkyPNG](http://chunkypng.com/) gem, which I wholeheartedly recommend for any of your pixel-by-pixel image generation needs.

Since this script takes the input data via standard input, it's meant to be used in a command like this:

```
ruby build_fractal.rb <fractal options> | ruby to_image.rb "X" 000 " " FFF fractal.png
```

which makes pretties like [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyOkI.jpg).

I'm looking for advice specifically on:

1. **Efficiency**: I want to spend as little time as possible drawing the image, so I can spend more time on generating the fractal.

That's it. Since this is purely a utility script that, as far as I can tell, is complete, there's no reason to worry about maintainability or code prettiness. I'm willing to sacrifice everything else to get every last bit of speed out of this.

Comment: Possibly related: [Generate fractals from bit patterns in ASCII](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54453/generate-fractals-from-bit-patterns-in-ascii)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Not particularly. This is about converting a block of ASCII directly to an image; it doesn't have to be fractals. That's more relevant to my fractal generator question.

Comment: Hence the "possibly". You want me to delete it and add the link on the other question (whatever it is)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> class Array
>   def chunk(chunk_size)
>     self.each_with_index.with_object(Array.new(size / chunk_size) { [] }) do |(elt, ind), result|
>       result[ind / chunk_size] << elt
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

You reinvented [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)! It returns an enumerator, which is fine for your code. Simply write `ARGV.each_slice(2).map do |char, color|` instead of `ARGV.chunk(2).map`.

> ```
> ARGV.length % 2 == 1
> ```

Change to `ARGV.length.odd?`.

> ```
> 'Run with -h to see usage.'
> ```

Doesn't work.

> ```
> colors = Hash[
>     ARGV.each_slice(2).map do |char, color|
>       color = ChunkyPNG::Color.from_hex(color)
>       [char, color]
>     end
> ]
> ```

I'd use `to_h` instead of `Hash[]` and inline `color`, to make the code shorter:

```
colors = ARGV.each_slice(2).map do |char, color|
  [char, ChunkyPNG::Color.from_hex(color)]
end.to_h
```

> ```
> text << $_.chomp.chars until $stdin.gets.nil?
> ```

Instead of creating many arrays of characters, simply store the strings. Remove the call to `.chars` and iterate over a string using `row.each_char.with_index`. This makes the code a little faster.

> ```
> raise ArgumentError, "No valid color provided for `#{char}`" if colors[char].nil?
> image[x, y] = colors[char]
> ```

ChuckyPNG already throws an ArgumentError if the color is nil. You can remove your check for this, which may improve performance. (If you need to catch this error, you can wrap the loop with a begin-rescue block)